# MVC C# Update a record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have something like the following code you see below as a template.
what are the different ways of doing an update with this record as the way I am doing it below does not work. I am using Entity Framework. C# is used as the language.

```
public ActionResult Edit(Truck_Mng truck_mng)
{
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {

        // what are the different ways you can update the truck_mng record
        // I tried what you see below but did not update the record

         DataContext.Truck_Mng.Attach(truck_mng);
         DataContext.SubmitChanges();

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
 return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

I am using Entity Framework.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework, Linq2Sql, DataSets?  You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Truck_Mng` is a class generated from a table in your database you can do the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Truck_Mng truck_mng)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Possible show an error message
        }

        using (var context = new MyDataContext())
        {
            context.Truck_Mng.AddObject(truck_mng);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
```

If `Truck_Mng` happens to be a model that you made then you will have to manually map it to the correct table like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Truck_Mng truck_mng)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Possible show an error message
        }

        using (var context = new MyDataContext())
        {
            context.SomeTable.AddObject(new SomeTable
                                            {
                                                TruckName = truck_mng.Name,
                                                TruckDest = truck_mng.Dest
                                            });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Do you know how to make it work with the SubmitChanges() as in my case, SaveChanges does not work

Comment: `SubmitChanges()` pertains to LINQ to SQL and `SaveChanges()` is Entity Framework. If you are using EF and SaveChanges isn't working there may be another problem.